# Calling a obj-c method with a parameter

Tags: c, objective-c, function, methods

I've change a c-style function to an objective-c method. As a method, how do i use it?

```
    NSString* myfunc( int x )

       is now:

    - (NSString *)myFuncWithParam:(int)x


 c code:  myString = myfunc(x);  // works

 obj-c code: myString = myFuncWithParam(x); // fails to compile.
```

From one of the answers:     myString = [object myFuncWithParam:x];

In that case, what would "object" be?

Comment: You should probably edit your question's title to be "Calling an objective-C method with a parameter".

Comment: I've updated my answer to describe what object is... You may want to study up a bit on object oriented programming before continuing with Obj-C since it's a very important concept.

Comment: You can't just slightly change the syntax and expect procedural C code to suddenly work as Objective-C. That's like appending "o" to all your words and imagining that you're speaking Spanish. You need to actually learn Objective-C.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`myString = [object myFuncWithParam:x];`

Where object is the object which has the method you're calling. If you're calling it from the same object, you'll use 'self'. [This tutoria](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)l might help you out in learning Obj-C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the square bracket "message" syntax:

myString = [myObject myFuncWithParam: value];

Answer (score 0):

Off topic/old man's ramblings:

Once, when I was bored, I tried to create a Obj-C-like syntax for C++ using operator overloading.  I believe I was able to get

```
myString = myObject[myFuncWithParam](value);
```

to work.